# How can I get around the Stadia Pro sign-up screen?

Tags: stadia

Whenever you create an account, it prompts me to make a Stadio Pro account and I can't seem to get around it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Even if you plan on answering your own question, the body should still be phrased like you are asking someone and you don't know the answer. I've fixed it for you; check it out!

Answer (score -1):

This is very much a loophole, so it may not work in the future.

You need a direct link to one of the free games (i.e. [This super bomberman link](https://stadia.google.com/games/super-bomberman-r-online)) to get past the pushy Pro screen. There, you'll find a direct sign up button that doesn't take you to Pro.